# Android KeyStore -> Persistencia

Tags: android

Actualmente me enfrento a cambiar la forma de guardado de "strings" en sharedpreferences hacia KeyStoreAndroid,

teniendo como premisa que KeyStoreAndroid puede persistir información para luego ser recuperada, pero cada vez que intento recuperar algun alias ya previamente registrado provoca errores,

KeyStoreAndroid persiste información como sharedpreferences pero de forma segura?, o no se usa para este proposito

Dejo codigo utilizado*

```
public class DeCryptor {
private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";

private KeyStore keyStore;

public DeCryptor() throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
        IOException {
    initKeyStore();
}

private void initKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
    keyStore.load(null);
}

public String decryptData(final String alias, final byte[] encryptedData, final byte[] encryptionIv)
        throws UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
        NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,
        BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
    final GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, encryptionIv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias), spec);

    return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedData), "UTF-8");
}

private SecretKey getSecretKey(final String alias) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        UnrecoverableEntryException, KeyStoreException {
    return ((KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null)).getSecretKey();
}
```

}

```
public class EnCryptor {
private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";

private byte[] encryption;
private byte[] iv;

public EnCryptor() {
}

public byte[] encryptText(final String alias, final String textToEncrypt)
        throws UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
        NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, SignatureException, BadPaddingException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException {

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias));

    iv = cipher.getIV();

    return (encryption = cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
}

@NonNull
private SecretKey getSecretKey(final String alias) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    final KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator
            .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);

    keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .build());

    return keyGenerator.generateKey();
}

public byte[] getEncryption() {
    return encryption;
}
```

public  byte[] getIv() {
return iv;
}
}

y lo uso asi ->

```
encryptor = new EnCryptor();

        try {
            decryptor = new DeCryptor();
        } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException |
                IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String pDeviceId = decryptpDeviceID();
        if(pDeviceId.equals("")){
            String a = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            encryptText(a);
        }

private String decryptpDeviceID() {
    String pDeviceId = "";
    try {
        pDeviceId = decryptor
                .decryptData("pDeviceId", encryptor.getEncryption(), encryptor.getIv());
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, pDeviceId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchPaddingException | IOException | UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pDeviceId;
}

private void encryptText(String pDeviceId) {

    try {
        final byte[] encryptedText = encryptor
                .encryptText("pDeviceId", pDeviceId);
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, Base64.encodeToString(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (UnrecoverableEntryException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | SignatureException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Bruno, es importante agregar la descripción del error que se provoca, saludos.

Comment: Ya agrego el error como tal,, pero mas allà de eso si deberia persistir?, osea yo encripto y desencripto con  KeyStore pero eso no persiste en el telefono o si? @Jorgesys